# Android: runtime OnClickListener does not work

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for Android devices using Eclipse and Android SDK;
I would like to add some ImageButtons (at runtime) with the same OnClickListener. The problem is that the OnClickListener works ONLY for the first added button. 
For all the next buttons the onClick event simply doesn't fire.

Have someone already encountered (and solved) this problem?

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
    ImageButton myButton= new ImageButton(this);
    myButton.setMaxHeight(140);
    myButton.setMaxWidth(140);    
    myButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    myButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    myButton.setImageResource(resId);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

        }
    });

    myRelativeLayout.addView(myButton, 0);
}
```

Comment: myButton.setFocusable(false) ....what happens?

Comment: you add the view always for the 0 zero index?

Comment: I see only 1 button. What is the error in your Log?

Comment: where are other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're always adding the button on the 0th position.

```
myRelativeLayout.addView(myButton, 0);
```

So you just create new buttons and add them as the "first button", which is probably why you only see that working. The buttons you created previously get lost.

Comment: I've tried to add the buttons at different positions (using a global counter), but doesn't go: the result at runtime is the same.

Comment: How are you testing that the OnClick doesn't fire?

Answer (score 0):

after you add the view, set the click listener like this

```
    final int count = myRelativeLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = myRelativeLayout.getChildAt(i);

        child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

                        public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

           }
            });
```

Comment: hi gldm, Did yout ried with my answer It worked for me.If you need I can put the detailed code